# ¿Cual es mas correcta para instanciar?

Tags: java, eclipse

Quiero instanciar objeto y estas dos opciones me dan bien, explico:
la clase edificio es el padre y la fabrica el hijo.
Edificio es abstracto.
Cual seria la mas correcta y/o que diferencias hay en las dos formas de hacerlo

```
Edificio edificio0 = new Fabrica();
Fabrica edificio1 = new Fabrica();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si bien es cierto ambas instancias son de la clase `Fabrica`.
Con el objeto `edificio0` no vas poder acceder a los métodos del hijo que en este caso viene a ser la clase `Fabrica` solo vas poder acceder a los métodos de la clase `Edificio`.
Con el objeto `edificio1` vas poder acceder tanto a los métodos del hijo como del padre, es decir a los métodos de la clase `Fabrica` y `Edificio`.
Solo como acotación, no se puede crear instancias de las clases abstractas.

Al no poder instanciar una clase abstracta, la forma para acceder a sus métodos se instancia mediante su hijo.

```
Edificio edificio0 = new Fabrica();
edificio0.metodoPadre();
```

también puedes hacer lo siguiente y es lo mismo

```
Edificio edificio0;
Fabrica edificio1 = new Fabrica();
edificio0=edificio1;
edificio0.metodoPadre();
```

En ambos casos sólo podrás acceder a los métodos del padre, tienes que tener en cuenta que la clase abstracta puede definir 1 o más métodos abstractos y estos métodos se deben sobre escribir o redefinir en las sub clases a esto se le llama **Polimorfismo**

Comment: Deberías incluir en tu explicación (la cual considero correcta) que esto es lo que se conoce como polimorfismo ya que de ahí provienen las restricciones y comportamientos que expones.

Comment: @E.Betanzos tienes razón se me pasó ese detalle, gracias